# Null control with XML SAX getValues()

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse the following xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gexf xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" version="1.2">
    <graph mode="static" defaultedgetype="directed">
        <nodes>
            <node id="0" label="Hello" />
            <node id="1" label="Word" />
        <node id="2" /> 
        </nodes>
        <edges>
            <edge id="0" source="0" target="1" />
        <edge id="1" source="1" target="2" weight="2.0" />
        </edges>
    </graph>
</gexf>
```

As can be seen some edges have weights, some do not.

My code is like the following:

```
elif name == "edge":
        u = attrs.getValue("source")
        v = attrs.getValue("target")
        w = attrs.getValue("weight")
        if w is not None:
            self.edgeweight = w
```

Here I expect w to be None on the first line and 2.0 on the second line of the XML file. Instead all I get is an error. What's the proper way to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get() method did the trick.

```
w = attrs.get("weight")
            if w is not None:
                self.weighted = True
                self.edgeweight = float(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
if attrs.hasKey("weight"):
    w = attrs.getValue("weight")
    self.edgeweight = w
```

I used [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.reader.html#attributes-objects) as reference. It doesn't specify if you can use `"weight" in attrs`, but you can try and see if it works.

Comment: 'AttributesImpl' object has no attribute 'hasKey'. I tried that before

Comment: If you're using Python 3, that doesn't seem to be available any longer. If `"weight" in attrs` doesn't work, try `print(dir(attrs))` to see what methods it has.